# Error #1069 Property CLICK not found...cannot addeventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, addeventlistener, referenceerror

Here's a simple code of rectangle drawing by mouse,and I'm going to add code for draging.but   I encounter an error
Error #1069: Property CLICK not found on flash.events.MouseEvent and there is no default value.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var mouseHolding:Boolean=false;
var posx:Number,posy:Number
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);
function mDown(MouseEvent){
    mouseHolding=true;
    posx=mouseX;
    posy=mouseY;
}
function mUp(MouseEvent){
    mouseHolding=false;
    var myDraw:MovieClip= new MovieClip();
    myDraw.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1);
    myDraw.graphics.beginFill(0x222222, 0.5);
    myDraw.graphics.drawRect(posx, posy, mouseX-posx, mouseY-posy);
    myDraw.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(myDraw);
    //problem line
    myDraw.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,objclick)}
function objclick(e:MouseEvent) {
    trace("fine");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this syntax for your event handlers:

```
function mUp( e:MouseEvent ){
```

And:

```
function mDown( e:MouseEvent ){
```

Comment: such a simple mistake and I can't find it.sigh.....I copy the drawing code from somewhere,for drawing purpose it has no problem,but didn't notice this,but thx.It's also self's fault of basic thing.........

Comment: @sbk201 it is ok , we are here to help each other !